# Change control text when property changes

Tags: vb.net

I need to change my label `MyLabel.Text` once property `Path` is changed. Look below my code. I know how to do it from outside my class `FrmImport` that i could just subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event however i am not sure how to do it from `FrmImport` class itself. You can see that i've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and created `OnPropertyChanged` which is called once path is set: `OnPropertyChanged("Path")`. Now i do not belive to subscribe my event in FrmImport itself but rather than that I think i just need to make somehow: `MyLabel.DataBindings.Add(??)` to make it work but right now stack on it. Can anybody help?

```
Public Class FrmImport
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
   Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(propName As String)
            If propName IsNot Nothing Then
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName))
            End If
        End Sub

        Private _path As String
        Public Property Path As String
            Get
                Return _path
            End Get
            Set
                _path = Value
                OnPropertyChanged("Path")
            End Set
        End Property


     Private Sub FrmImport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ' ??? MyLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.Path)
        End Sub
```

or should i just make like this without any INotifyProperty usage?:

```
Public Property Path As String
                Get
                    Return _path
                End Get
                Set
                    _path = Value
                    OnPropertyChanged("Path")
                    MyLabel.Text= Me.Path
                End Set
            End Property
```

Comment: If you want to do it using an event (although I don't know why you would) then you would do it in exactly the same way inside as outside.  Why not just set the `Text` of the `Label` in the property setter though?  Why get cute and force yourself to write more useless code?

Comment: Looks like you took my recommendation as I was writing.  Yes, you should just do it that second way.  There's no point raising an event and handling it in the same class.  Handling something like `Load` is different, because it's raised in the base class.  Handling an event that you raised in the same code file is pointless.

Comment: I did it before seeing that comment :) I know it's pointless however just from technical perspective knowledge how to correctly add binding i started because i feel like it would work :  ??? MyLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.Path)

Comment: As I said, it would be the same inside as outside.  How do you call that `Add` method outside?  You pass the name of the control property, the data source object and the name of the data source property.  You don't pass the name of the control property and the current value of the data source property.

Comment: What are you using for your UI?  WinForms?  WPF?  Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do binding when the data is stored outside of the form. For example, if you had a PathInformation class with a bunch of properties that needed to be displayed. There need to be something in place for the class to tell the form it got updated and the form to tell to class to update itself.

When the variable is directly in the form, binding isn't really needed. Just update the path directly. No need for OnPropertyChanged because nothing outside of the form need to know of the change (since they already called the Path property).

But this is borderline opinion and depends also on the rest of the code.